# Error while compiling under cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin, linker-errors

I am using cygwin on a 64 bit OS. This error occurs every time, when I compile my code:

> (.rdata$.refptr.__stdout[.refptr.__stdout]+0x0): undefined reference to `__stdout'

I tried to include `stdio.h` but no changes happen.

Comment: undefined reference to `__stdout', it means __stdout is not visible to linker .. link it against appropriate library.

Comment: You've not given enough detail - it would help to see the link line that produces the error.

Comment: the link line is not specified when the error generates,only the file is shown...which is really big.I want to know what libraries to include so __stdout is visible to the linker.

Comment: But show us some more output from the compilation process - we need to know how the linker is invoked and so on.

Comment: Thank you all...I got the solution,the makefile that I had written,was missing a $ symbol.... Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: No Answer. OP fixed issue but did not leave solution for their case. Question is Old and not likely to ever be answered. I Suggest removal